# docker missing var/lib/docker folder

Tags: docker

I was trying to do something, but I have accidentally deleted docker folder at var/lib/docker, and now I can not install another docker any more. What to do now? How can I fix this problem and install new docker.

```
sudo docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
9bb5a5d4561a: Pulling fs layer 
docker: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob974250330: no such file or directory.
```

See 'docker run --help'.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

have you tried to simply restart docker this way?

`systemctl restart docker`

or

```
sudo service docker stop
sudo service docker start
```

Comment: Great! You may accept the answer as correct, if it solved :)